# __lookupGetter__ VS getOwnPropertyDescriptor to retrieve a getter

Tags: javascript, html, getter, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to set a getter for the "HTMLStyleElement.prototype.innerHTML" .
but i still need to retrieve the native one so i can call it when i'm done.
if i will use `__lookupGetter__` like this:

```
HTMLStyleElement.prototype.__lookupGetter__("innerHTML")
```

i will get the original getter , but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupGetter__) this feature has been removed from the web standards.

so i tried using

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()
```

like this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLStyleElement.prototype,"innerHTML").get
```

but for some reason it will return "undefined" , so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: One of the reasons `Object.prototype.__lookupGetter__` was deprecated was because it returns a getter found anywhere in the prototype chain which can produce undesired results. The accepted answer shows how `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` fixed that issue by only returning a getter if one is an own property of object. `Object.prototype.__lookupGetter__` is however only deprecated. It wasn't removed from the web standards.

Answer (score 4):

The `.innerHTML` property is inherited. `__lookupGetter__` seems to take that into account, but when using `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` you will need to retrieve it from `Element.prototype` where it is defined:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype,"innerHTML").get
```

Comment: Great Thanks! perfect answer